# How to get a view from a resource?

Tags: android

I have a UI, I build it dynamically. I should want to put some component in a xml resource file. So I do :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+android:id/titreItem"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

... in a file `res/layout/titreitem.xml` as I see anywhere. But I don't understand how get it to put inside my UI. So, inside `activity.onCreate`, I want to do something like :

```
RelativeLayout myBigOne = new RelativeLayout(this);
TextView thingFromXML = [what here ? ];
myBigOne.addView(thingFromXML);
setContentView(myBigOne);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approach seems to be little incorrect. You should put RelativeLayout to the xml as your TextView made, and inflate the whole xml. Afterwards, you will be free to add views to your layout. So, do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+androi:id/relLayout>
  <TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+android:id/titreItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.titreitem);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewByid(R.id.relLayout);
layout.addView(...);
```

Comment: Thanks also to st0le; His answer is intersting, but I only have one "accepted answer" :-)

Answer (score 35):

Use a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)....The Entire Layout can be inflated, without dynamically creating it....

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View theview = li.inflate(R.layout.whatever, null);
```