# How to get EditText by xml id Java Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I am new to the android sdk. I have this weird gui thing and I made a Button and an EditText inside of it. I think I properly set up the onClick stuff for the button, but how to I get the text inside of the EditText with the id of editText1 from what it says inside the xml file? Here is my EditText xml element inside of the xml file:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/test"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|none" >

    <requestFocus />
```

Thanks! Sorry that I am so new to Android development. None of the things I have searched make an sense to me. I keep seeing stuff about the "R" class and I have no idea what that means.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a view from a resource?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358242/how-to-get-a-view-from-a-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text inside the EditText do that:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String yourText = editText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting learning from https://developer.android.com/training/

In `onCreate()` of your source code say MainActivity.java

Try this!

```
final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

in `onClick()` listener of your button, try `String ss=et.getText().toString();`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To get the text entered inside of your EditText, you would do the following inside of your onClick:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String words = et.getText().toString();
```

Then do whatever you want with the text with the variable.